# Power series that converges conditionally at the endpoints of its interval of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, conditional-convergence

As we know, for the power series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(x-x_0)^n,$$
it will have a convergence radius $R$ and $R$ is non-negative. I want to know whether there exists a power series example that its convergence domain is $[-R,R]$ (that is a closed domain) and in particular, the power series on $x=R$ and $x=-R$ are both conditionally convergent?

It’s easy to find an example that power series on $x=R$ and $x=-R$ are absolutely convergent. But it is difficult to find the (both $R$ and $-R$) convergent case.

Answer (score 7):

Take, for instance,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}nx^{2n}.$$Its radius of convergence is $1$ and it converges conditionally when $x=\pm1$.

Comment: But it is about $x^{2n}$, the general form of the power series is about $x^{n}$, whether it doesn't matter that the power is $2n$.

Comment: Are you somehow saying that my series is **not** a power series?

Comment: @Linge You can easily express this series in the usual form $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k x^k$$ by letting $a_k = 0$ for odd $k$, and $a_k = (-1)^{k/2} / (k/2)$ for even $k$. I don't know why this answer received downvotes; it looks correct to me.

Comment: Oh I make sense