# A power series that converges conditionally for all points on the radius of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

For $a_n\in\Bbb C$ let
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n z^n \tag 1$$
be a power series with radius of convergence of 1, and $a_n$ such that the series converges for all $z\in\Bbb C$ with $|z|=1$.
What's unclear to me is whether this tells anything about absolute convergence for $|z|=1$ like:

> Must there be at least one $z$ with $|z|=1$ such that $(1)$ converges absolutely?

So I am trying to find a counter-example, i.e. a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $(1)$ only converges conditionally for all $|z|=1$.

The idea is to use $$a_n=\frac1n \exp(2\pi i g_n), \qquad g_n\in\Bbb R$$
and find a suitable sequence $g_n$. As $|z|=1$, it can be represented as $z=\exp(2\pi i \phi)$, $\phi\in\Bbb R$ so that $(1)$ becomes

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1n \exp(2\pi i(g_n + n\phi)) \tag 2$$

The series based on $(2)$ does not converge absolutely by construction. Can $g_n$ be chosen in such a way, that $(2)$ converges irrespective of the value of $\phi$?

Intuitively, $g_n$ has to be chosen in such a way that the arguments of $a_n$ are distributed evenly enough so that the series conveges for all $\phi$, but no idea how to make that explicit, resp. show that all such series are converging.

---

Note: I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4209542/746312) which is the same, but limited to real power series only.

Comment: an easy example (with uniform conditional convergence on the unit circle, hence $f$ extending to a continuous function on the closed unit disc) is $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{e^{in \log n}}{n}z^n$ since it is not that hard to show that $\sum_{n \le N}e^{in \log n}e^{ix}=O(\sqrt N)$ uniformly in $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ say, by standard exponential series methods; taking the real part of the coefficients, one gets such an example with real coefficients (though the fact that $\sum |\cos (n \log n)|/n =\infty$ requires some extra proof)

Comment: I serached for *"standard exponential series methods"* but ofund nothing useful or related.

Comment: in this case one applies the second derivative test (and binary summation in intervals ) (since for $g(x)=\frac {x\log x+x}{2 \pi}$ one has $g'(x)=2+\log x$ increasing and $g''(x) = 1/x$ so on any interval of length $K$ the exponential sum $\sum_{K \le n \le 2K}\exp {2\pi ig(x)} = O(\sqrt K)$ and then one splits $N$ in the usual binary way in such intervals ($[N/2, N], [N/4, N/2]$ etc; look into any decent (analytic number theory) book with exponential sums  (for example Graham and Kolesnik monograph) or for this example, Zygmund bible on Trigonometric series has it worked out in chapter 5 4.7

Comment: What about $a_n$=1/n^2?

Comment: @Lawrence the series converges absolutely then

Comment: Another way to look into this stuff, is to look into the uniform algebra on the disc (holomorphic functions with continuous extensions to the disc) and examples of such that do not belong to the Wiener algebra $A$ (the ones with absolute convergent series on the disc) - that should be treated in books on spaces of analytic functions in addition to books like Zygmund; depends on your interest in such

Comment: @Conrad You are correct.

Comment: @Lawrence see my comments above where you can find classical examples of such (theory of Fourier series or the more specialized part of the uniform disc algebra and its Wiener subalgebra - your function belongs in the Wiener subalgebra)

Comment: If it converges absolutely for at least one $z$ with $|z|=1$, then it converges absolutely for all $z$ with $|z|=1$. This is equivalent to convergence of $\sum|a_n|$, which clearly doesn't depend on the angle of $z$.